# How do I send this form's output to a new Wordpress page?

Tags: jquery

On [this site](http://test.doig.com.au/meyer/), I have the following form which allows a visitor to select from a choice of mortgage calculators to use:

```
<select id="dynamic_select" name="cars">
<option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Borrowing-Power-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Borrowing Power Calculator</option>
...
</select><input id="Submitgo" type="submit" style="float:right; clear:both;"/></p>
<br class="cleanBreak" />

<script>// <![CDATA[
$('#Submitgo').on('click', function() { var url = $('#dynamic_select').val(); window.location = url; });
// ]]></script>
```

When the form selection is chosen, and the submit button is clicked, the user is taken to an external page where the calculator is displayed.

I would like the form to display within a new Wordpress page.

Unfortunately I am designer, not a developer, so I do not know where to start.

I gather perhaps I can change `window.location = url` to equate to a Wordpress URL?

Perhaps I need to embed the url within an iframe? However, I don't know how to get the window.location to forward to a Wordpress page with an iframe containing the calculator URL.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can add per form through iframe in new wordpress page then you can redirect after select change.

Comment: Is this done with a Shortcode or is the Form directly in the `post_content` of this page?

Comment: Hi @fischi, at this stage I do not know. I don't see how it could work with a shortcode.

Comment: decided not to downvote, but this is a horrible question, with almost zero useful info. What research have you done, what options have you tried?

Comment: Can you clear more your question?

Comment: Added some detail to the question. Hope this makes things more clear?

Comment: Is http://www.visionabacus.com/ your website? Is that form yours? If it's not you have two options: 1 is just as Devendra Sharma suggested to use an iFrame; the second one is to code the form.

Comment: The visionabacus.com is not our website. The form is not ours. We are renting them. The problems is that I am not a developer, and I do not know how to get the form into an iframe on a new Wordpress page.

Comment: Have you tried googling it? if you're not familiar with codes you should just use iframe, here is a little trick <iframe src="" class="hidden"> if select option value calculator, then show it

Comment: Hi @nackle. I have tried Googling it, and didn't find much help. As I am not a developer, i will need someone to provide an explicit answer with code.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use Iframe in this case. Here is how I will do it. Do you really need the submit button? in this case I do it without submit button, you can change it to your needs. This example codes can be added to your WordPress page through **Text** Tab on editor

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hideframe {
        visibility:collapse;
        display:hidden;
        height:0px;
    }
</style>

<select id="car" name="car">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="calc">Borrowing Power Calculator</option>    
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById( 'car' ).onchange = function() {
            var calc = document.getElementById( 'calc' );
            if( this.value === 'calc' ) {
                calc.classList.remove( 'hideframe' );
            } else {
                calc.classList.add( 'hideframe' );
            }
        };
    }
</script>

<!-- iframe start -->

<div id="calc" class="hideframe">
    <iframe src="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Borrowing-Power-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA" />
</div>
<!-- iframe end -->
```

Comment: Great. I appreciate this @nackle.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have access to this website and form your best bet will be to use an `<iframe>`. Paste this in some page:

```
<iframe src="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Borrowing-Power-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA"  style="height: 100%; width: 700px;">
  <p>
    <a href="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Borrowing-Power-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">
      Fallback link for browsers that, unlikely, don't support frames
    </a>
  </p>
</iframe>
```

Although keep in mind that some browsers won't show the form as well as if you use it on a page with `HTTPS` the form won't be show and you will get `Mixed Content` errors.

Comment: Thanks @denis. Note that this does not provide a drop down box of calculators to choose from, which is a requirement of the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should get results using below code:

```
$( "#dynamic_select" ).change( function() {
    var changingUrl = $( this ).val();
    window.location = changingUrl;
} );
```

Here you will get a selected option URL by selecting an option from the select box as:

```
var changingUrl = $( this ).val();
```

Then redirect the page as you want using:

```
window.location = changingUrl;
```

Comment: Please don´t post only code. Explain what it does, how it does that and why you think it should work in the context of the question.